# New site has PR9 as soon as it is made, why/how?

Tags: pagerank

I was just messing around with [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/) and noticed that as soon as I made my site the homepage had a PR of 9 (before it crosses your mind all the links it makes are `nofollow`).

The homepage of the test site I was playing around with is https://sites.google.com/site/samsnewsite030413/

Why does this happen as PR is on a per-page basis, and as the page is brand new how does it have a PR? I've seen a similar thing happen with Github project pages; they seem to have a PR8 as soon as they are made, it's not like they are running off a standard URL with JavaScript bringing in the content - they seem to be static pages with their own URLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not PageRank of your home page but PageRank of https://sites.google.com.

You can check PageRank of Github home page [here](http://www.prchecker.info/check_page_rank.php) and you will see PR8.

This comes from *HTTPS* misunderstood. If you want the real PageRank of your page, check it with *HTTP*. I have checked it and your PageRank is N/A.

Comment: So if a page is using https:// it will display the PR of the homepage / root

Comment: That's correct!