# How to find Google PageRank of a SSL/HTTPS Page

Tags: google, https, pagerank

If a page is using HTTPS it will display its page rank as the page rank of its homepage, for instance this page is displaying a PR8 - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/publiser45/

But that's actually the PR of the root of the subdomain, any idea how i can get the PR of an actual page, on a site that uses HTTPS ?

Comment: I gave you the solution on my answer of your last question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46845/new-site-has-pr9-as-soon-as-its-made-why-how/46846#46846

Comment: its not really the same question, as it didnt address, finding the actualy pr just that it was being displayed incorrectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you update or change the PR tool you are using to check pagerank since its clearly not working. HTTPS and HTTP are protocols and are treated exactly the same by Google, PR will be the same on both.

**Working as intended on FireFox**

[Google Page Rank in Firefox http://www.bybe.net/downloads/firefox-pr.jpg](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/firefox-pr.jpg)

**Working as intended on Chrome**

[Google Page Rank in Chrome http://www.bybe.net/downloads/chrome-pr.jpg](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/chrome-pr.jpg)

**Google PageRank**

As you can see the PR is 0 for this page.

Comment: thanks, whats the name of the firefox pr tool you are using ?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pagerank/contribute/roadblock/?src=userprofile&version=2.0

Comment: Images are broken.

Comment: Will address shortly, thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebRank Toolbar 4.4 for you Chrome Browser. It will show the real and clear PR as well as Alexa Rank, Similar Sites, Pages Indexed in Google,Bing, Whois Dmain checker and other SEO Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Id like to chime in on this question simply because i run a few SSL sites one used to be non-SSL and i turned it full SSL

But take paypal for instance.

- `https://www.Paypal.com` has PR8
- `http://www paypal.com` redirects to the https version.

If google treated pagerank exactly the same on SSLvsNON i'd argue that a page such as:

`https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/paypal-fees` (paypals fee's page) would show some PR and would not be given PR0 by google, its physically impossible.

So what i've always believed is that google will run site wide PR when using HTTPS.

On the site i used that was nonSSL and is now SSL, the non SSL pages was individually ranked, since switching to SSL only, those pages do remain individually ranked on one google PR checker.

But on the other, it shows the site wide PR.

[image]